# Rmd/Kntir: Markdown citations in LaTeX environments

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I want to create a `threeparttable` in a Rmd/Knitr-document and to add a note to the bottom of the table. The table is created by a R-function inside a chunk with `results = "asis"`. I did not add the function to the working example because it's quite verbose and the problem is evident from the pure LaTeX code.

This works and the result looks as expected.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
references:
- id: rao2001basic
  title: Basic Research in Parapsychology
  author:
  - family: Rao
    given: K.R.
  issued:
    year: 2001
  publisher: McFarland
  type: book
---

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{A summary table of the cars dataset.}
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
Descriptives & speed & dist\\
\midrule
Mean & 15.4 & 42.98\\
SD & 5.29 & 25.77\\
Min & 4 & 2\\
Max & 25 & 120\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\tablenotes{\item\textit{Note.} This table was created by @rao2001basic. }
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the citation in the table caption is not working. It works fine if I take it out of the LaTeX environment, but not inside. Is there a way to parse the Markdown in the LaTeX environment?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Pandoc does not parse markdown inside raw tex blocks. Would it be possible to have your code output a markdown table instead of latex?

Comment: I don't think this type of table formatting is possible in pandoc as of now.

Comment: Since you are using a function to generate the table, you could have it split in two where it emits the citation and write to two files instead, then use `\input{part1.txt} [@rao2001basic] \input{part2.txt}. Though it might be easier and more reproducible to use an external bib file.

Comment: Addition of this feature has recently been suggested https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2453

Comment: Would using `knitcitations` be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you are willing to use the `bookdown::pdf_document2()` format, you can use [text references](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#text-references) to solves this problem without having to mess with LaTeX:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
header-includes:
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
references:
- id: rao2001basic
  title: Basic Research in Parapsychology
  author:
  - family: Rao
    given: K.R.
  issued:
    year: 2001
  publisher: McFarland
  type: book
---

(ref:tablenote)
This table was created by @rao2001basic.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{A summary table of the cars dataset.}
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
Descriptives & speed & dist\\
\midrule
Mean & 15.4 & 42.98\\
SD & 5.29 & 25.77\\
Min & 4 & 2\\
Max & 25 & 120\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\tablenotes{\item\textit{Note.} (ref:tablenote)}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

This even works when tables are created by in R:

````
```{r results = "asis"}
knitr::kable(mtcars[1:3, ], caption = "(ref:tablenote)")
```
````

Answer (score 4):

This sort of issue is essentially an escaping issue or rather an avoidance issue of pandoc's automatic latex block begin/end recognition.

This particular case could be written with the environment commands directly as

```
\table[h]
\centering
\threeparttable
\caption{A summary table of the cars dataset.}
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
Descriptives & speed & dist\\
\midrule
Mean & 15.4 & 42.98\\
SD & 5.29 & 25.77\\
Min & 4 & 2\\
Max & 25 & 120\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\tablenotes[flushleft]
\item\textit{Note.} This table was created by @rao2001basic.
\endtablenotes
\endthreeparttable
\endtable
```

but if the `begin{env}`/`end{env}` are truly needed then macros can be used like this

```
\def \btable{\begin{table}}
\def \etable{\end{table}}
\def \bthreeparttable{\begin{threeparttable}}
\def \ethreeparttable{\end{threeparttable}}
\def \btablenotes{\begin{tablenotes}}
\def \etablenotes{\end{tablenotes}}
```

It would be nice if a robust generic solution existed for renaming of `begin{env}`/`end{env}` that could allow *selective* markdown within tex blocks. Something like...

```
\newcommand\mdbegin[2]{%
  \ifstrempty{#1}{%
    \begin{#2}
  }{%
    \begin{#1}[#2]
  }%
}

\newcommand\mdend[1]{%
  \end{#1}
}
```

which works for this, using the `etoolbox` package, but I don't think it would be a recommended solution.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this looks like it might just work for my purposes. I'll take a closer look.